# IPA SIL keyboard - letters missing

Tags: input-encodings, extended-characters

I'm using the IPA SIL keyboard to write letters in latex.
When I want the letter 'ɒ' , I type the shortcut '=o' (where =is a hotkey).
Similarly 'a̯' is typed as 'a&*'.
The problem arises when I use a special letter as in the first example and then want to add the diacritic symbol to it.
then. In this case, the engine only compiles the diacritic.

MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage[
             backend=biber,
             style=unified,
             autocite=footnote,
             citestyle=authoryear,
             %babel=other,
             natbib
            ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{seiler.bib}
\date{}
\author{} 
\title{report }
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{introduction}
ɑ̯ a̯ o̯ ɒ̯ 
\end{document}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCuq9.png)

Notice, that in my editor (neovim). I cannot see the diacritics, I mention this, because maybe the problem lies there?

[image]

Comment: you get warnings in the log: `Missing character: There is no ɑ (U+0251) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!`. Switch to a font which actually support your chars.

Comment: My Bad! Sorry for the attention